# Web scraper for e-commerce sites Part II

Tags: c#, factory-method

I asked the same question [Web scraper for e-commerce sites](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/282602/implementation-of-factory-pattern?noredirect=1#comment560356_282602) yesterday and I'm now posting the revised code here.

I'm building web scraper application which takes name, code and price from few sites. I thought factory pattern would fit in my application. I would like to someone review my code and tell if I'm missing something.

I have class `Item` which holds scraped data.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

An interfacem which has a method `RunScrapingAsync` with a list of item codes as the single parameter, which I need to scrape.

```
public interface IWebScraper
{
    Task<List<Item>> RunScrapingAsync(List<string> itemCodes);
}
```

Then I have implementations for three scrapers (Amazon, EBay, AliExpress):

```
public class AmazonWebScraper : IWebScraper
{
    private static HttpClient client;
    public List<string> ItemCodes { get; set; }

    public AmazonWebScraper()
    {
        client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Proxy = null });
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://amazon.com");
    }

    public async Task<List<Item>> RunScrapingAsync(List<string> itemCodes)
    {
         ConcurrentBag<Item> itemsConcurrentBag = new ConcurrentBag<Item>();
         //for simplicity this logic is not important no need to go in details
         return itemsConcurrentBag.ToList();
    }
}

public class EBayWebScraper : IWebScraper
{
    private static HttpClient client;
    public List<string> ItemCodes { get; set; }

    public EBayWebScraper()
    {
        client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Proxy = null });
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://ebay.com");
    }

    public async Task<List<Item>> RunScrapingAsync(List<string> itemCodes)
    {
         ConcurrentBag<Item> itemsConcurrentBag = new ConcurrentBag<Item>();
         //for simplicity this logic is not important no need to go in details
         return itemsConcurrentBag.ToList();
    }
}

public class AliExpressWebScraper : IWebScraper
{
    private static HttpClient client;
    public List<string> ItemCodes { get; set; }

    public AliExpressWebScraper()
    {
        client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Proxy = null });
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://aliexpress.com");
    }

    public async Task<List<Item>> RunScrapingAsync(List<string> itemCodes)
    {
         ConcurrentBag<Item> itemsConcurrentBag = new ConcurrentBag<Item>();
         //for simplicity this logic is not important no need to go in details
         return itemsConcurrentBag.ToList();
    }
}
```

Here is my factory class `WebScraperFactory`:

```
public enum WebSite
{
     Amazon,
     EBay,
     AliExpress
}

public class WebScraperFactory
{
    public IWebScraper Create(WebSite website)
    {
       switch (website)
        {
            case WebSite.Amazon:
                return new AmazonWebScraper();
            case WebSite.EBay:
                return new EBayWebScraper();
            case WebSite.AliExpress:
                return new AliExpressWebScraper();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException($"Not implemented create method in scraper factory for website {webSite}");
        }
    }
}
```

The `WebScraper` class, which holds all scrapers in a dictionary and uses them in the `Execute` method for the provided `WebSite`.

```
public class WebScraper
{
    private readonly WebScraperFactory _webScraperFactory;

    public WebScraper()
    {
        _webScraperFactory = new WebScraperFactory();
    }

    public async Task<List<Item>> Execute(WebSite webSite, List<string> itemCodes) =>
        await _webScraperFactory.Create(webSite).RunScrapingAsync(itemCodes);
}
```

This is a WinForm app, so users have the option to run one or more scrapers (they are not all mandatory to run). So if a user chooses to run Amazon and AliExpress, it will choose two files with codes, adds them to the dictionary and calls the webscraper factory on every chosen website.

Example usage:

```
var codes = new Dictionary<WebSite, List<string>>
{
    {WebSite.Amazon, amazonCodes},
    {WebSite.AliExpress, aliExpressCodes}
}

var items = new Dictionary<WebSite, List<Item>>
{
    {WebSite.Amazon, null},
    {WebSite.AliExpress, null}
}

var webScraper = new WebScraper();

foreach(var webSite in websitesItemCodes.Keys)
{
    items[webSite] = await webScraper.Execute(webSite, codes[webSite]);
}
```

Comment: Having a `static` `HttpClient` but assigning it in a non-static constructor is, for all intents and purposes, *wrong*. Either remove the `static`, or inject the entire `HttpClient` into your object and have it truly static elsewhere.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer thanks for advice.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `IWebScraper`

- Based on the implementations it seems like you would gain more if you would define this interface as an abstract class to have a common place for the shared logic

```
public abstract class WebScraperBase
{
    private readonly HttpClient client;

    public WebScraperBase(Uri domain)
       => client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = domain };

    public async Task<List<Item>> RunScrapingAsync(List<string> itemCodes, CancellationToken token = default)
    {
         ConcurrentBag<Item> itemsConcurrentBag = new();
         
         await ScrapeAsync(itemCodes, itemsConcurrentBag, token);

         return itemsConcurrentBag.ToList();
    }

    protected abstract Task ScrapeAsync(List<string> itemCodes, ConcurrentBag<Item> items, CancellationToken token);
}
```

- I think the whole handler object is unnecessary: `new HttpClientHandler() { Proxy = null }`
- I changed your `RunScrapingAsync` to be a [template method](https://reactiveprogramming.io/blog/en/design-patterns/template-method)

  - I've added a `CancellationToken` as a parameter to allow user cancellation/timeout
  - I also defined a `ScrapeAsync` method as a *step method*
- I'm not sure why do have a class level `List<string>` property and a `List<string>` parameter as well

  - I've removed the former because based on the shared code fragment it was not in use
  - If it was in use inside the not shown part of the code under the `RunScrapingAsync` then please be aware that this property could be modified while the async method is running!!!!

### `XYZWebScraper`

- After the above changes the implementation of a given scraper could look like this

```
public class AliExpressWebScraper : WebScraperBase
{
    public AliExpressWebScraper() : base(new Uri("https://aliexpress.com"))
    {}

    protected async override Task ScrapeAsync(List<string> itemCodes, ConcurrentBag<Item> items, CancellationToken token)
    {
        //for simplicity this logic is not important no need to go in 
    }
}
```

### `WebScraperFactory`

- If you could take advantage of [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) then you can rewrite your `Create` like this

```
public static WebScraperBase Create(WebSite website)
    => website switch
    {
        WebSite.Amazon => new AmazonWebScraper(),
        WebSite.EBay => new EBayWebScraper(),
        WebSite.AliExpress => new AliExpressWebScraper(),
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"Not implemented create method in scraper factory for website {webSite}"),
    };
```

#### `WebScraper`

- I do believe this whole class is unnecessary if you define the `WebScraperFactory` and its `Create` method as `static` (like above)

---

**UPDATE #1**
I completely overlooked that the `client` was defined as `static` inside the `WebScraperBase`. That implementation does not work so here are two alternatives:

1. Store the static `HttpClient` instances inside the `WebScraperFactory` and pass them to the ctor of the concrete scrapper instances

`WebScraperFactory`

```
private static Dictionary<WebSite, HttpClient> clients = new Dictionary<WebSite, HttpClient>
{
    { WebSite.Amazon, new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://amazon.com") } },
    { WebSite.EBay, new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://ebay.com") } },
    { WebSite.AliExpress, new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://aliexpress.com") } }

};

public static WebScraperBase Create(WebSite website)
{
    var client = clients.ContainsKey(website) ? clients[website] : throw new InvalidOperationException("...");
    switch(website)
    {
        case WebSite.Amazon: return new AmazonWebScraper(client);
        case WebSite.EBay: return new EBayWebScraper(client);
        case WebSite.AliExpress: return new AliExpressWebScraper(client);
        default: throw new NotImplementedException("...");
    };
}
```

`WebScraperBase`

```
private readonly HttpClient client;

public WebScraperBase(HttpClient client)
    => this.client = client;
```

2. Use `IHttpClientFactory` to delegate the life cycle management of the underlying `HttpClientHandler`s to a dedicated component

   - Because you are using .NET Framework, not .NET Core you need to do the [following workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73642025/unable-to-make-httpclientfactory-working-from-a-net-framework-4-7-2-winform-pro/73855685#73855685) to be able to use `IHttpClientFactory`

`WebScraperFactory`

```
private static readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
static WebScraperFactory()
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection().AddHttpClient();
    serviceCollection.AddHttpClient(WebSite.Amazon.ToString(), c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://amazon.com"));
    serviceCollection.AddHttpClient(WebSite.EBay.ToString(), c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://ebay.com"));
    serviceCollection.AddHttpClient(WebSite.AliExpress.ToString(), c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://aliexpress.com"));
    serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
}

public static WebScraperBase Create(WebSite website)
{
    var factory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    var client = factory.CreateClient(website.ToString());
    if(client.BaseAddress == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("...");
    switch(website)
    {
        case WebSite.Amazon: return new AmazonWebScraper(client);
        case WebSite.EBay: return new EBayWebScraper(client);
        case WebSite.AliExpress: return new AliExpressWebScraper(client);
        default: throw new NotImplementedException("...");
    };
}
```

Comment: Application is written in .Net framework so I can't use pattern matching switch. Would use it if I could.

Comment: @Xyloto Even thought I read WinForms, I did not realisize it means dotNet Fw in this case...

Comment: `abstract` classes cannot have `static` members. I suppose that is because an abstract class is never instantiated.

Comment: @radarbob Quite frankly I overlooked that part. Let me update my post.

Comment: @radarbob I've extended my post to address that issue

Comment: @Xyloto I've updated my post please revisit it